# Formatear una hora en c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime

Tengo una función que me calcula las horas de diferencia entre dos fechas y funciona perfectamente, el problema es que **me entrega la hora completa con segundos y milisegundos**

Esta es lo que me entrega: `02:44:50.0958404`

Y lo que necesito es: `02:44`

He intentado usar `toString()` de la siguiente forma: `result.ToString("HH:mm");`, pero no funciono, dejo el codigo a continuacion

```
public static string CalcularTiempoHoras(string fecha)
{
  DateTime FechaIngresada = DateTime.Parse(fecha);
  TimeSpan result = DateTime.Now - FechaIngresada;
  //Asi no me funciono
  //string result2 = result.ToString("HH:mm");
  //return result2;

  return result.ToString();//asi me devuelve la hora completa.
}
```

Comment: Estas casí correcto, solo convierte el valor 02:44:50.0958404 a DateTime, agregué respuesta,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso te pasa porque result es un timespan.

`ToString("HH:mm")` esto te funcionaria si fuera un DateTime.

Si quieres entregar el resultado en formato HH:mm puedes hacer esto:

```
public static string CalcularTiempoHoras(string fecha)
{
  DateTime FechaIngresada = DateTime.Parse(fecha);
  TimeSpan result = DateTime.Now - FechaIngresada;
  return string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", result.TotalHours, result.Minutes);
}
```

Por ejemplo con una diferencia de 20 días esto te va a entregar 480:00
(24x20=480)

Comment: En realidad, solo obtengo las horas cuando el tiempo el menor a un dia. Tu respuesta cumple con lo requerido, te lo agradezco y acepto tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente, cambia el formato a `DateTime`:

```
 DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("02:44:50.0958404", "HH:mm:ss.fffffff",
                                   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

posteriormente aplica el uso de `.ToString("HH:mm")` como lo tratas de realizar:

```
String hourMinute = myDate.ToString("HH:mm");
```

de esta forma a partir del valor original `"02:44:50.0958404"` obtendrías

```
02:44
```

---

Este sería el método:

```
public static string CalcularTiempoHoras(string fecha)
{
    DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "HH:mm:ss.fffffff",
                               System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);    
    return result.ToString("HH:mm");
}
```